# Are questions about "the biggest city/province/country in region Y in the year Z" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Because of poorly thought out questions in the past, I want to make sure that my question wouldn't cause me even more trouble than I'm already in. I want to know what the biggest pre-Gaul/Celtic settlements in the region the Romans called Gallia Belgica around 1000 BC were as research for my book. Is that question on-topic?

More generally, are questions concerning location population numbers in a specific timeframe on topic?

Comment: I have only one vote, but I would probably upvote such a question.

Comment: Seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the five upvotes to the two comments, I'm going to conclude that there is a consensus that these questions are on topic.  (In reality, there are possibly as few as 3 upvotes, but I'm going to hazard that we still have a weak consensus).

In my opinion, this class of questions 
* Relies on historical records
* results in a (relatively) clear answer.  (All meaningful answers are estimates with a confidence interval).
* Are useful in the practice and advancement of history.

Obviously the question will be most successful if we can pin down the time and geography;  I think you've done that in the example.

Dissent invited, but I wanted to provide an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I might have been tempted to "follow along with already established VtC's", but having come here first to request clarification will instead cause (enable?) me to support keeping it.